# Replacing the body of a specific function in python code

Tags: python

Assume that I have a python source file, the names of a specific class and a  from this file, and a string to replace the body of that function. How can I write a program to do this automatically? I am not looking for "string"-matching solutions. I am mostly looking for a python library that might facilitate this task.

To clarify, the main challenge I am facing is:
"How to locate the said class/function since it can be nested like class/function/function, or many other ways"

Here is an example:

INPUT:

```
# old.py
class C:
  def f1():
    # body_stmts_f1

  def g1(j):
    a = 10
    b = 30
    return a + b * j


# class/function of interest: C, g1


# new_g1_body.py
  def g1(j):
    a = 40
    x = 100
    return a - x + j
```

OUTPUT:

```
class C:
  def f1():
    # body_stmts_f1

  def g1(j):
    a = 40
    x = 100
    return a - x + j
```

Comment: You can't replace *method* with *function*, but if you'll add first argument `self`, you can use `C.g1 = g1`.

Comment: cant you just read the python code through an InputStream as string change the text and then save the file?

Comment: Sorry about the vague question. I edited the question to clarify it. The main question is how to systematically locate the function that I want to replace in the string that I read from `old.py`.

Comment: What if two classes have a method with the same name? your approach to attack this problem is suboptimal, you should specify the full path to the function that you want to replace, not just the name of it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for two classes to have the same function names. So the input string specifies the complete path, e.g., `Class1.func1.inner_func2` when we want to replace `inner_func2` which is located inside `func1` that is located inside `Class1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Python's own AST package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). First, I `parse` the original file, then I find the function that I want to change using `visitors`, then I make the desired changes to that function. Finally, I `unparse` the modified AST.

Answer (score 0):

```
# old.py
class C:
  def f1():
    # body_stmts_f1

  def g1():
    # body_stmts_g1


# class/function of interest: C, g1


# new_g1_body.py
def g1():
  # new_body_stmts_g1

C.g1 = g1
```